# right aligned reference labels with multibib

Tags: reference, alignment, latex, label

I am using multibib to include a reference list after each section. I added some code in order to make the reference labels look like [a.1],[a.2], ... where a is the section number.
It looks like the reference labels are left-aligned, which makes the text of the reference shift to the right, when having more than 9 entries.
I would like to have the labels right-aligned, such that the text after the label starts always at the same position. Is there an option in multibib I overlooked?

It is highly likely, that this is not exactly a mwe.
Thank you for your help

My texfile.tex is:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[numbers,square,comma]{natbib}
\usepackage[resetlabels]{multibib}
\usepackage{totcount}
\newcites{sec}{Refs: Section 1}
\newcommand\newcite[3]{\citetext{\ref{#1}:\citealp#2{#3}}}
\renewcommand\bibsection{\subsection{\refname}}
\makeatletter
\newtotcounter{citenum}
\def\@mb@citenamelist{cite,citep,citet,citealp,citealt,citepalias,citetalias}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}\label{sec:sec1}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{[\ref{sec:sec1}:\stepcounter{citenum}#1]}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\newcite}[1]{\citetext{\ref{sec:sec1}:\citealpsec{#1}}}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\noindent\newcite{knuth1986texbook1}
\noindent\newcite{knuth1986texbook2}
\noindent\newcite{knuth1986texbook3}
\noindent\newcite{knuth1986texbook4}
\noindent\newcite{knuth1986texbook5}
\noindent\newcite{knuth1986texbook6}
\noindent\newcite{knuth1986texbook7}
\noindent\newcite{knuth1986texbook8}
\noindent\newcite{knuth1986texbook9}
\noindent\newcite{knuth1986texbook10}
\bgroup
\let\section\subsection
\bibliographystylesec{unsrt}
\bibliographysec{bibfile}
\egroup
\end{document}
```

My bibfile.bib is:

```
@book{knuth1986texbook1,
  title={The texbook},
  author={Knuth, Donald Ervin and Bibby, Duane},
  volume={1993},
  year={1986},
  publisher={Addison-Wesley Reading, MA, USA}
}
@book{knuth1986texbook2,
  title={The texbook},
  author={Knuth, Donald Ervin and Bibby, Duane},
  volume={1993},
  year={1986},
  publisher={Addison-Wesley Reading, MA, USA}
}
@book{knuth1986texbook3,
  title={The texbook},
  author={Knuth, Donald Ervin and Bibby, Duane},
  volume={1993},
  year={1986},
  publisher={Addison-Wesley Reading, MA, USA}
}
@book{knuth1986texbook4,
  title={The texbook},
  author={Knuth, Donald Ervin and Bibby, Duane},
  volume={1993},
  year={1986},
  publisher={Addison-Wesley Reading, MA, USA}
}
@book{knuth1986texbook5,
  title={The texbook},
  author={Knuth, Donald Ervin and Bibby, Duane},
  volume={1993},
  year={1986},
  publisher={Addison-Wesley Reading, MA, USA}
}
@book{knuth1986texbook6,
  title={The texbook},
  author={Knuth, Donald Ervin and Bibby, Duane},
  volume={1993},
  year={1986},
  publisher={Addison-Wesley Reading, MA, USA}
}
@book{knuth1986texbook7,
  title={The texbook},
  author={Knuth, Donald Ervin and Bibby, Duane},
  volume={1993},
  year={1986},
  publisher={Addison-Wesley Reading, MA, USA}
}
@book{knuth1986texbook8,
  title={The texbook},
  author={Knuth, Donald Ervin and Bibby, Duane},
  volume={1993},
  year={1986},
  publisher={Addison-Wesley Reading, MA, USA}
}
@book{knuth1986texbook9,
  title={The texbook},
  author={Knuth, Donald Ervin and Bibby, Duane},
  volume={1993},
  year={1986},
  publisher={Addison-Wesley Reading, MA, USA}
}
@book{knuth1986texbook10,
  title={The texbook},
  author={Knuth, Donald Ervin and Bibby, Duane},
  volume={1993},
  year={1986},
  publisher={Addison-Wesley Reading, MA, USA}
}
```

Comment: see "multibib & indentation" in the tex section

Answer (score 1):

The evolved solution to this problem was suggested by egreg on Feb 13 2013 [Link to the stackexchange site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97991/multibib-indentation)

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{%
  \section*{\refname}\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}%
}{}{}{}
\begingroup\catcode`#=12
\AtBeginDocument{
  \patchcmd\thebibliography
    {\advance\@tempcnta#1}
    {\advance\@tempcnta#1\else\@tempcnta#1}
    {}{}
}
\endgroup
\makeatother
```

Comment: Hello! Sorry, instead of re-posting other people's work, it would be better to just flag the whole question for migration to that site, where it belongs. It can be then marked as a duplicate of the question where **egreg** provided a solution, if this is considered appropriate.